# How can set my button a random color to the background. Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Sorry for my bad English I'm a beginner of android and now I'm stuck.

Now my Question is how can I set the random colors to the background with the `OnClickListener`. Can you maybe help my with this problem?

I have one class (Kleurenpalet.java)

```html
 package com.example.pstek.randomcolor;

import android.graphics.Color;

import java.util.Random;

public class Kleurenpalet{

    private static String[] kleur = {
            "#39add1", // light blue
            "#3079ab", // dark blue
            "#3FD52D", // green
            "FFFF0000", // red

            ""};

    public  int getRandomColor() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int color = rand.nextInt(kleur.length);

        return Color.parseColor(kleur[color]);
    }

}
```

And I have my main class :

```html
package com.example.pstek.tegeltjeswijsheid;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ConstraintLayout layout;
    private Button randombutton;
    int randomColor = new Kleurenpalet().getRandomColor();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        randombutton = findViewById(R.id.button);



        randombutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), ;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the MainActivity code this :

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ConstraintLayout layout;
  private Button randombutton;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    randombutton = findViewById(R.id.button);



    randombutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int randomColor = new Kleurenpalet().getRandomColor();
            layout.setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
        }
     });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps call [`setBackgroundColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)) with the initialized color:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
```

Or a different one each time:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(new Kleurenpalet().getRandomColor());
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you try to do here:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), ;
```

Why did you leave empty space there? Moreover, if you parse color in your `Kleurenpalet`, you must use without `ContextCompat`. Just set your color like this:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
```

`ContextCompat` is *for parsing color from resources file*, for instance:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            R.color.colorPrimary
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put "Random Num" and "layout set Color" in button click event :

```
randombutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int randomColor = new Kleurenpalet().getRandomColor();
            layout.setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
        }
     });
```